# Is it possible to put Kile's Live preview in separate window?

Tags: kile

As in the title. I have two monitors, and I'd like to have the live preview on the secondary one, while the rest of the Kile on the main one.

I could use Ocular, but it doesn't always auto-update the view, for some reason.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/kile/mailman/message/4522955/ or maybe here http://latex-community.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=20 or here http://kile.sourceforge.net/Documentation/html/build_preview.html

Answer (score 9):

If you use Kile 3 beta (here I use 2.9.60) -- the one with live update of the .pdf I mean, then it is easily done:

under Kile >> settings >> configure Kile >> Appearance you have a 'Document Viewer' setting and you can tick 'show in external window' -> problem solved.

For older versions of kile I cannot be sure -- but you do not have live preview on those, so I suppose you are on the same verison as me.